# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare- (previously declared in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, fatal-error

im a php noob
trying to use a plugin called featured item slider for wordpress

-when i use **shortcode** to place it to pages or posts it **works fine**.
-**problem** is when i try to place it to my template via **php include** i get this error

(Fatal error: Cannot redeclare featured_options_page() (previously declared in /home/infostar/public_html/wp-content/plugins/featured-item-slider/featured-item-slider.php:36) in /home/infostar/public_html/wp-content/plugins/featured-item-slider/featured-item-slider.php on line 37)

i ve tryed so far
 **include_once**  when i use it i get no errors but nothing showing 
 **require_once** again no erros but i plugin not showing 
 **get_included_files** still no error but nothing showing

i dont think probably including the file functions.php more than once because it works fine when i call it with shortcode

can someone expert help me???

Answer (score 2):

How are you posting the shortcode in the template?

Here is the correct format according to a wordpress support thread.
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/short-code-outside-page-or-post

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[catlist id=1 numberposts=5)]'); ?>
```

The actual shortcode goes in with the square brackets.